# What is pinPtrArray with respect to setting up this Mat container?

Tags: opencv, c++-cli

This bit of code is from a device supplier for which I am utilizing their libraries. I am no programming expert by any means and need to understand this for a research project.

```
pin_ptr<System::Byte> pinPtrArray;
pinPtrArray = &e->GetImageData->dataRawPixels2Byte[0];
Mat im (e->Width, e->Height, CV_16U, pinPtrArray);
```

Does anyone understand what `pin_ptr<System::Byte>` is? Furthermore, what does implementing this into a Mat container do? If someone could explain, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh.aspx) you have detailed explanation of `pin_ptr`. In managed world of C++/CLI (.NET Framework) objects in heap (in memory) are managed by garbage collector. It can move objects in order to prevent memory fragmentation. It can also delete object if the object is out of scope. When you are using managed memory in native environment (here `Mat` is native object and `e` is managed) you have to "pin" this managed object in order to prevent the object pointed to from moving on the managed heap. Now you can use data pointed by `pinPtrArray` safely. Garbage collector will not move it during runtime.

Comment: I would change the link address to the one in English :) Great answer

Comment: @RickM. Thanks mate! Corrected :)